# PHP - How to check values inside of an array that they don't have the same value?

Tags: php

```
$name = array("Bryan", "Jason", "Kevin")
```

From this array, I want to make sure that these values does not match (does not equal to each other). How can I do it in php?

Comment: Apply `array_unique` to remove any duplicates, and then compare the `count` of the new resulting array, to that of the original one.

Comment: `if (count(array_unique($name))==count($name)) {// all are unique`